# Clustered file services failure causes all nodes down?

Tags: filesystems, cluster

I am planning a cluster of 3 active-active nodes running Red Hat Linux 6.7, with local and shared file systems, such that the 3 servers can read / write some shared files concurrently. However, my system administrator told me that if the clustered file service is down, then all 3 nodes will go down, is there any clustering approach to overcome it?

Comment: It _might_ depend on the clustering implementation you're using. But you've forgotten to tell us what that is.

Comment: One approach would be to have the shared filesystems be NFS filesystems, and the NFS server be a NetApp or some other NAS device with sufficient redundancy built-in. Or you might build your own NFS server cluster using DRBD, and have the worker nodes rely on that for shared filesystems. But still, if your workers need shared storage and it's down, then the workers will be unable to work too. The only way around it is replicating the data instead of sharing it, and that brings with it the problem of keeping the replicas in sync with each other. [...]

Comment: [...] If there is a chance that one of the workers is using a version of shared data that is out-of-sync with the others, then that worker **must stop immediately** and not pass on the stale data. Essentially, you must be able to treat the worker systems as **expendable**.

Answer (score 1):

Your admin is correct, if you have a single shared OS between nodes in a clustered filesystem and the clustering fails, all nodes are down as they would not be able to access important files necessary for operation.

You are also correct, if each node has its own OS and the clustering fails, you should only lose access to files within the cluster as the necessary operating system files would be local.  You do not mention what clustering you are using, so there may need to be some further mechanisms to make sure a failed cluster does not otherwise hang the system.

It seems like your clustering would still be a single point of failure for the shared files, but if it does not take out entire hosts that may make your admin feel better.